# VS Code extension for PHP code navigation

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I am developing Laravel PHP application on Mamp stack.

Is there any extension which can help in code navigation (Go to implementation ) ?

I have PHP intellisense by Felix Becker but it does not provide code navigation. Have searched online but did not find any extension providing code navigation.

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: There're at least three extensions that provide such feature, including the one you mention. I presume you've had issues making it work or your specific framework follows some pattern to declare stuff that the extension doesn't understand. I think you should edit the question and try to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Vs code for php sucks but for the sake of answering your code unrelated question which this is not the place for it Try php intelliphense